# How do I prevent losing precision when saving a DateTime to MongoDb using the 2.0 C# Driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, datetime

Currently when we are serializing and saving an object that contains a DateTime to MongoDb using the 2.0 C# Driver we are losing precision so when it is compared as part of a concurrency check it is failing as the ticks are different.

I found a [blog post](http://alexmg.com/datetime-precision-with-mongodb-and-the-c-driver/) that describes how to maintain the precision using the original C# driver by using `DateTimeSerializationOptions` and specifying a BsonType of Document but I cannot find an example online of how to do this in the new version.

What is the equivalent for the code below in the new driver?

```
DateTimeSerializationOptions.Defaults = new DateTimeSerializationOptions(DateTimeKind.Utc, BsonType.Document);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging through the source code for the serializers on GitHub I came up with the following which works.

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(typeof(DateTime), new DateTimeSerializer(DateTimeKind.Utc, BsonType.Document))
```

Comment: It's worth re-saving all documents after this change. Otherwise If You will have document based on the default DateTime format and also some with new format, some comparisons based on DateTime might not work as expected and might cause unexpected issues.